# SelectionChanged fired twice instead of once

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I have a list box with selection change event, but when I select some item it fired twice, here my code:

```
<ListBox SelectedValue="{Binding CleanedSelected}" ItemsSource="{Binding ScanedDiskList}"  >
           <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                 <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                     <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding SelectionChangedCleaned_Command, Mode=OneWay}" />
                   </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
  </ListBox>
```

where:

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
xmlns:cmd="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"
```

Comment: What is `SelectedValue="{Binding CleanedSelected}"` doing? Besides that, if you bind SelectedValue, you typically also set SelectedValuePath. Otherwise, bind SelectedItem.

Comment: not 100% sure if that is still the case but I remember a combo box was always going back to `-1` before going to the actually selected index. Try debugging if you enter your event with -1 and if that's the case return else `run your code`

Comment: @Denis and Rekshino. The question is about ListBox, not ComboBox, which behave differently.